# Proof Οf Τhe Variance Οf $\hat y_{x_0}$

Tags: statistics, regression, covariance, linear-regression, regression-analysis

**EXERCISE**

> Show in a simple linear regression model that the variance of $\hat y_{x_0}=\hat b_0+\hat b_1x$  is:
>   $$V(\hat y_{x_0})=σ^2 \dfrac {\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i^2}{n \cdot \sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i-\bar x)^2}+ \dfrac{σ^2\cdot x_0}{\sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i-\bar x)}-\dfrac{2x_0σ^2 \bar x}{\sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i-\bar x)}=σ^2 [\cdot \dfrac{1}{n}+ \dfrac{(x_0-\bar x)^2}{S_{xx}}]$$

**ATTEMPT**

Ok, my first option was:
We know that $$V(y_{x_0})=V(\hat b_0+ \hat b_1x_0)$$
After i used that: $$\hat b_0=\bar y-\hat b \bar x$$ and
$$\hat b_1= \dfrac{S_{xy}}{S_{xx}}$$ but i didn't reach to any conclusion.

**Can anyone help me with this exercise? It's the only exercise from a total number of 8 exercises of this type that I don't know how to proceed and I can't find anything that can help me to solve this!**

I would really, really appreciate any thorough help or hints/tips.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/60306/proving-textvar-haty-h-sigma2-left-frac1n-fracx-h-bar.

Comment: @StubbornAtom thanks!I'll check it!